# How do I tell Java that an interface implements Comparable?

Tags: java, class, interface, comparable

I have an interface named **IDebt**, and a class implementing said interface named **Debt**.

I also have a list made of objects implementing the IDebt interface:

```
List<IDebt> debtList = new ArrayList<IDebt>();
```

The class **Debt** implements Comparable, but when I do **Collections.sort(debtList)** I get an error, because Java has no way to know that the object implementing IDebt as such implements Comparable.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot. Your `List` could contain `SpiderDept`, which does not `implements` anything...

Comment: Are all `IDebt`s intended to be comparable to all other `IDebt`s? (Particularly, should instances of two different implementations be comparable to each other?)

Comment: See the breakline answer.  TLDR: have IDebt extend the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static interface MyInterface extends Comparable<MyInterface> {

}

public static class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyInterface another) {
        return 0; //write a comparison method here
    }
}
```

Then

```
List<MyInterface> test = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(test);
```

will work

Update: also for sorting maybe this makes more sense:

```
Collections.sort(test, new Comparator<MyInterface >() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyInterface lhs, MyInterface rhs) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is then a question of how you compare to disparate objects.

Comment: You can use an actual comparator for sorting, I usually do that, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Make your `IDept` interface extend `Comparable`

```
interface IDept extends Comparable{
    ....
}
```

Interfaces can extend other Interfaces.